# EXEC call works but sp_executesql fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a stored procedure with I can call like so:

```
EXEC usp_GetDataExport '2016-06-01', 3, 302653, 2
```

this returns data as expected

However when this called from an application/SSIS package, I can see from the profiler that it is interpreted as:

```
EXEC sp_executesql
        N'EXECUTE usp_GetDataExport @P1, @P2, @P3, @P4'
      , N'@P1 datetime2(1), @P2 varchar(2), @P3 varchar(3), @P4 varchar(4)'
      , '2016-06-01'
      , '3'
      , '302653'
      , '2'
```

This call returns empty data. I have run this from a new query window and it fails to return data as well. I am not sure how to investigate this further. could you help please? Thanks

Comment: `@P3 varchar(3) = '302653'` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `exec` the three columns are numbers, presumably integers:

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXECUTE usp_GetDataExport  @P1, @P2, @P3, @P4',
                   N'@P1 datetime2(1), @P2 int, @P3 int, @P4 int',
                   '2016-06-01', 3, 302653 , 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was it. Should have known

Comment: But apparently the sp_executesql statement is being 'seen' by the profiler with varchar data type parameters and not integers. This is when the SSIS package executes. How do you suppose I prevent this? The datatype of the parameters are set in the SSIS task as NUMERIC and the SPROC accepts int datatype also. Thanks

Comment: This is really weird.  Are you sure there aren't two different versions of usp_GetDataExport, one with params 2 to 4 defined as int and one with them defined as varchar?  Maybe in two different schemas?  Or two different databases?  Or the same-named database on two different servers?

Comment: @SebTHU: Thanks, I have checked once and again and there isn't. Worth a recheck though. Thanks